# How many socket.io objects can be held in a JS object in memory before noticeable degradation of performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a bit of a strange website design. I am using socket.io and have to maintain the socket object of each connected user in order to funnel responses from a separate applicaton.

I am storing the sockets like this:

```
var clients = {};

//further down, in socket.io code:
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    ....
```

When client requests come in, I include the socket id and send it for processing to another application. When the response comes in, I deque the connection and:

```
if(returned_object.socketid){
    if(clients[d.socketid]){
        clients[d.socketid].emit('res', returned_object);
    }
    ...
```

Realistically, how many concurrent connections could I expect before I notice performance lag? I'm wondering if it's in the tens, or hundreds, or thousands. Obviously, I am using `delete` on each socket `disconnect`.

I have also considered writing each socket to disk on connection with `leveldb` or some other database.

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer but from personal experience - assuming reasonable code you should be able to do several thousands on a server, and scale that by persisting clients to REDIS (or a DB) instead of memory and having several servers communicate through that. Not terribly hard to get to 50k concurrent users if all you want is messaging.

Comment: FYI, you do not have to maintain your own map of sockets indexed by their id.  That is already done for you automatically by socket.io in `io.sockets.connected`.  It is exactly what your `clients` object is already except it is maintained automatically for you by socket.io.

Comment: If you configure your server appropriately for a large number of open sockets, you may be limited by the amount of traffic you can process with a single process long before you have memory issues from your number of connections.  So, unless most sockets sit idle, your actual scaling is probably limited by traffic processing concerns which you haven't mentioned anything about.

Comment: @jfriend00: You may be right. However, at current levels of traffic, that shouldn't be an issue. The application can handle multiple requests concurrently via a worker threadpool and hasn't shown any sign of being remotely throttled. I do hope that's the limiting factor here.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell just as a follow-up, I found this to be very interesting.  http://www.http-kit.org/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html  They mention 250k concurrent connections on a relatively modest machine, running with no problemo.  Of course, the 600k is when they run their whole setup using Clojure and http-kit, but it has links to node benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten thousand is a good estimate before you start seeing performance "drops," and even then, probably not noticeable until you reach 20k or 50k socket objects.  If you consider the size in memory of a socket object versus that of a standard Apache connection (2-3MB per connection last I read) then you really don't have much to be concerned about.